# Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in smarty

Tags: smarty, notice

I got the following notices and would like to clarify:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /homepages/40/d35550088/htdocs/smarty/templates_c/
ef666588706a0451c86287e631024054e2f40226.file.list.tpl.php on line 434 

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /homepages/40/d35550088/htdocs/smarty/templates_c/
ef666588706a0451c86287e631024054e2f40226.file.list.tpl.php on line 434 

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in /homepages/40/d35550088/htdocs/smarty/templates_c/
ef666588706a0451c86287e631024054e2f40226.file.list.tpl.php on line 434  

Notice: Undefined offset: 9 in /homepages/40/d35550088/htdocs/smarty/templates_c/
ef666588706a0451c86287e631024054e2f40226.file.list.tpl.php on line 434
```

Code lines in the compiled tpl are:

`<?php if ($_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['TablesLinked']->value[$_smarty_tpl->getVariable('smarty')->value['section']['i']['index']]){?>`

This is the uncompiled line:

`{if $TablesLinked[i]}`

One line above starts the section:

`{section name=i loop=$NumberFields}`

Do I have to change the start index because offset means wrong index ?
TablesLinked does not appear in every field, because fields consist of linkedtables and normal fields, thats why I use an if-clause.

I hope you can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is a very good practice set error_reporting to E_ALL during development phase and trying to eliminate all notices, personally I wouldn't worry about these messages. It just won't find the elements on the specified indices during the loop. In any case, if you insist on eliminating the notices, you can change

```
{if $TablesLinked[i]}
```

to

```
{if isset($TablesLinked[i]) && $TablesLinked[i]}
```